# react handling development imports of subproject when package is published on npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am using react with create-react-app and I have a subproject inside my project, which I uploaded to npm. When I don't want to develop on the subproject everything works fine. I can import my subproject with npm and use the react components. But when I want I want to develop on the subproject I clone it into my rootproject and I have to adjust all imports from the npm package.

For example

```
import foo from 'foo'
```

have to been changed to

```
import foo from './foo'
```

Is there a solution to bypass the change of all imports when I want to develop on my subproject?